# Data List Row Css

Tags: asp.net

Is There Any Way To Apply Css To Every Row In DataList (Asp.NEt)

Answer (score 0):

There's two way :

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlMembers" runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="YOURCLASS">
    <ItemTemplate>
         [...]
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Or

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlMembers" runat="server">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="YOURCLASS" />
    <ItemTemplate>
         [...]
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Withing DataList template:  [asp.net datalist - change styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046531/asp-net-datalist-change-styling)

Dynamically at run time: http://forums.asp.net/p/1626231/4181111.aspx